# How to click a button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Super basic question. How do I trigger the clicking of a button in javascript?

Here's the relevant code

```
<button class="button--unstyled link-without-visited-state inline-block font-size-inherit topcard-see-more-link" type="button">See all</button>
```

I know the solution is something like this

```
document.getElementById("myButton").click();
```

I'm new to this unsure what from the code I would replace with "myButton" and if anything goes inside the click parentheses

Comment: This is indeed a basic question that can be solved through basic research. What sources have you found so far?

Comment: `document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListner('click', yourFunction)`

Comment: Well your button doesnt have an id so you wouldnt replace "mybutton" as much as you would replace the method you are using, ie use querySelector with proper selector or similar method. And click() doesnt take any arguments, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click#Syntax

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're using getElementById, you need to give your element an Id. Without which, it's not going to work, so in your case:

```
<button id="myButton" class="button--unstyled link-without-visited-state inline-block font-size-inherit topcard-see-more-link" type="button">See all</button>
```

Next, we'll set up the button so it can be referenced later

```
const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
```

Finally, we'll add a click event listener:

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

This is going to add a click listener to our button and fire the myFunction function when it's clicked.

There's a couple of others ways to achieve the same thing. I would suggest checking out MDN for more details!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking for an element with id="myButton", but it is probably returning `null`; it will work if you add the `id` property to the button:

```html
<button id="myButton" class="......"></button>
```